# Regular Expression Match for Google Analytics Goal Tracking

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I have a coupon request form on every page on my website, when the coupon form is submitted you are taken to the same page you are on with an additional "?coupon=sent" parameter added to the query string. I would like to be able to track any page url wiht ?coupon=sent on the end as a goal. Currently, I have this:

> /[^.]*[.php]*[\?coupon\=sent]+

which does not seem to be doing the trick. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this one:

```
/\?coupon=sent/
```